# Select issue in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a problem when I try to extract from table (modele) all data from 'marca' (marca contains nokia, samsung, etc)

so I try to use `$_GET` but is is not working. I can select a line from table just with `$_GET` id but this does not help me, because I want to make categories selectable from links so sql inject like `localhost/article.php?marca=nokia` (must appear just nokia phones) I think is the best way.

For now I am using code wich shows me last 5 posts sorted by id but it is not working correctly because it show nokia, samsung, htc, nokia, other, nokia.

```
<?php require 'SQL.php';

$id = isset($_GET['id'])?(int)$_GET['id']:0; // daca $_GET['id'] exista, folosestel ca      integer, altfel trucul sentinel, de obicei id incepe cu 1, deci 0 va functiona

if ($id!=0): 
// Vom procesa daca exista doar 1 inregisrare in baza de date
$query = 'SELECT marca FROM modele WHERE id='. $id .' LIMIT 1'; // voi folosi 1,    nemaiavand nevoie de alti pasi pentru lookup in sql
else:$query = 'SELECT marca FROM modele ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5'; 
endif;

$result = mysql_query($query);
// now loop through the results
while($linie = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // le voi utiliza dupa bunul plac
    echo ''.$linie["marca"].'<br />';
} 
?>
```

to work properly it must show me only nokia, nokia, nokia what's missing?

If is another way, please let me know!

Comment: BTW: Read about SQL Injection, I hope this code is only for testing purpose, in final product you should escape variables that come from users into SQL query

Comment: Beware [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327).

Comment: :) After you read about SQL Injection, consider that in your case the simplest way to prevent SQL Injection is just to: `$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using the following query:

```
   SELECT marca FROM modele ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

you are displaying all `marca` from `modele` you should add `where` clause, e.g.

```
   SELECT marca FROM modele 
   where marca = 'nokia'
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

You can retrieve the `marca` name from GET using `$_GET["marca"]`.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

Read also about sql injection, cause I fell that you will get there.

Comment: SELECT marca FROM modele 
   where marca = 'nokia'
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
 
gived me an error but with

SELECT marca FROM modele 
   where marca = "nokia"
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 

Worked good and thankyou for help and for your good intentions!